# Create new subdocument in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

What am I missing here? I want to add a sub document to the User schema I already have the schema predefined else where.

```
User.findById(req.body.id, function(err, user) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        reivews: [{
            reviewer: req.body.name,
            content: req.body.content
        }]
        user.save(function(err) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            res.send('saved')
        })
    })
```

It's saying its saved but I don't see the review in the for the user with the id I tried to save to.

Schema

```
const Review = new Schema({
    reviewer: String,
    date    : { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    content : String,
    isLive  : { type: Boolean, default: false }
});

const User = new Schema({
        username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
        password: { type: String, required: true },
        createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
        reviews: [Review]

});

User.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Review', Review);
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', User);
```

Comment: Are you sure the syntax is correct. It should be `user.reviews.push({reviewer: req.body.name, content: req.body.content});`

Comment: I am still getting saved but I am not seeing the new subdocument nothing seems to be saving

Comment: I want to add a new subdocument to a document that already exists. I am not trying to update a subdocument...

Comment: If you are trying to save a subdocument, the syntax should be `user.reviews = {reviewer: req.body.name, content: req.body.content};`. And, do you see anything on console from where you are running your http server. Because `res.send()` will always execute, even when there is an error.

Comment: Also, share the Schema definition for User and Reviews

Comment: I have added the schema to my original question. I do see errors but they are from passportLocalMongoose as it thinks I am creating a new user. I want to add a new subdocument to an existing user

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166890/discussion-between-rohit-aggarwal-and-joe-hill).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
User.findById(req.body.id, function(err, user) { 
  if (err) return console.log(err); 
  if (user.reviews === undefined || user.reviews.length == 0) { 
    user.reviews = []; 
  } 
  user.reviews.push({ 
    reviewer: req.body.name, 
    content: req.body.content 
  }); 
  user.save(function(err) { 
    if (err) console.log(err); 
    res.send('saved') 
  }) 
})
```

And ensure that data in `user` as per the defined Schema

Comment: This is correct but I also had another error where I was requiring there to be a password and thus not saving the review as the User schema validation failed